# In spinner, Display country names with alphabets in android. While scrolling it will show the alphabets left side

Tags: android, xml

I am having the list of countries in spinner.Its in ascending order only. But i wanna show the alphabets in left side separately. By pressing the alphabets, it will show the corresponding countries.I am Storing the data in strings.xml 
            
                Select
                Afghanistan
                ......
                Zimbabwe
            
For example, if i press A , it will show 'A' alphabet countries.

Comment: How are you storing data? Database? Array created at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Refer these [docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29)

`public void sort (Comparator<? super T> comparator)`

Sorts the content of this adapter using the specified comparator.

The comparator used to sort the objects contained in this adapter.